# Build variadic tuple from array to return

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, variadic

I want to have a method to build a tuple with variable number or entries based on how many entries an object has in a member variable container (e.g. vector).

This is what I've got as my best result. Not working, however. I'm obviously missing something in return value construction. Let's say `m_values` is a container with values I want to put into a tuple and return.

```
template<typename... T>
std::tuple<T...> getValuesTuple()
{
    if (m_values[0].isValid())
    {
        return buildReturnTuple(0);
    }
    return std::tuple<T...>();
}

template<typename... T>
std::tuple<T...> buildReturnTuple(size_t i)
{
    if (i + 1 < MAX_VALUES && m_values[i + 1].isValid())
    {
        return std::tuple<T, T...>(m_values[i], buildReturnTuple(i + 1));
    }

    return std::tuple<T...>(m_values[i]...);
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you have to know number of elements in vector in compile time. Otherwise it is impossible to do what you want

Comment: may be look at `std::make_tuple` ? Create the vector *v* containing the expected values then create the tuple using  `std::make_tuple(v.size(), begin(v), end(v));`

Comment: @bartop thank you for the answer. I'm fine with having an array with (as already noted in code) MAX_VALUES constant array size known at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know size of array at compile time, it can be done in way like this:

```
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

struct MyType {};

constexpr auto my_type_to_any_other_type(const MyType&) {
    // use if constexpr to return desired types
    return 0;
}

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t... Idx>
constexpr auto array_to_tuple_helper(const std::array<MyType, N>& a, std::index_sequence<Idx...>) {
    return std::make_tuple(my_type_to_any_other_type(a[Idx])...);
}

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto array_to_tuple(const std::array<MyType, N>& a) {
    return array_to_tuple_helper(a, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

int main () {
    auto t = array_to_tuple(std::array<MyType, 1>{ MyType{} });
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The types of variables in C++ is a compile time property.

The type a function returns is a compile time property.

What you are asking to do cannot be done, because a 2 element tuple is a different type than a 3 element tuple.

There are related techniques based off `std::variant` or even `std::any` but they are unlikely to be what you want.

You need to step back and look at your motivating problem that made you want the data stored as a tuple here and find a different path.